Is this the correct equation for divergence of a horizontal vector field in spherical coordinates?
There is a Horizontal vector field $\textbf{V} = <u\hat{\lambda}+v\hat{\theta_{lat}} + 0\hat{\textbf{r}}>$ which is gridded along Earth's surface. Physically speaking, the vector field's components are gridded in coordinates of (longitude$^{\circ}$,latitude$^{\circ}$) with $\lambda$ being longitude and $\theta_{lat}$ being latitude, and the components $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ point purely in the longitudinal and latitudinal directions, respectively; there is no vertical component, nor do the vectors' positions vary with height (displacement from origin (0,0,0)). Mathematically speaking, $\lambda$ would be the angle between $\textbf{r}$ and the x-axis on the x-y plane, $\theta$ would be the declination angle or the angle between $\textbf{r}$ and the x-y plane which would mean $\theta_{lat} = 90-\theta$ where $\theta$ would be the angle from the z-axis which is traditionally what $\theta$ would represent in spherical coordinates, and the vectors as functions of position (unless I'm mistaken) are:
$$\textbf{u} = \textbf{u}(\lambda,\theta_{lat}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \textbf{v}= \textbf{v}(\lambda,\theta_{lat})$$ with each vector being along the Earth's surface which is $6.378*10^6$m from the center of the Earth.
With that setup out of the way, I came across this formula for divergence of this horizontal vector field in a research paper:
$$\tag{1}\delta = \frac{1}{\sigma}\Big[\frac{\partial u}{\partial \lambda}+\frac{\partial (\sigma v)}{\partial \theta}\Big]$$
where $\delta$ is divergence, and $\sigma = \cos(\theta_{lat})$, and notably $r$ is not present here likely because this horizontal vector field lacks a vertical (or $\hat{\textbf{r}}$) pointing component.
In comparison between this equation and this divergence equation in spherical coordinates which assumes a 3-D vector field with components pointing in the $\hat{\lambda}$, $\hat{\theta}$, and $\hat{\textbf{r}}$ directions:
$$\tag{2} \delta = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \big(r(w)\big)}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial \big(\sin(\theta)(v)\big)}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial \big((u)\big)}{\partial \lambda}$$ where $w$ would be the vertical ($\hat{\textbf{r}}$) pointing velocity component of the vector field, which in our case is 0.
To be clear, I neither know very little about how the divergence operator actually works (especially in non-Cartesian coordinate schemes), nor do I want to open that can of worms (not yet at least), my aim was to get someone who maybe does know how it works if they could verify if equation (1) is in fact the equation for divergence for a horizontal vector field lacking a component which points in the direction of $\hat{\textbf{r}}$.
I'm not asking to show the derivation either, a simple "yes" or "no" would be fine.

EDIT: I have performed a sample calculation using (1) to compute divergence

The values were about 25-33% too large in most places for the above plot and we can see from the colormap on the right that the divergence values appear larger, but within the correct order of magnitude

The values in this above plot were about 3-5% off in most places, but varied fairly largely in places, though the colormap shows fairly close results overall.

Have we not learned in the previous question how to do those derivations? This is recommended because making quotes such as (2) is likely to mess up the conventions: when $\lambda$ is inside $\sin$ this can impossibly be the angle that you call longitude.

@KurtG. I just checked "with θ the angle with the z-axis", so that's egg on my face, I believe this is the version for physics majors when θ is the angle from the z-axis; I'll move to make a correction on that. Additionally, the latitude does not directly translate either because θ is angle from the pole whereas latitude is angle from the equator (x-y plane), or the declination angle, so it would be $\theta_{lat}=90−\theta$. I'll have to read these things more carefully!

@KurtG. Additionally, I just realized $\cos(\theta_{lat}) = \cos(90-\theta) = \sin(\theta)$

Sounds like progress. Now a hint: (1) is a special case of (2).

@KurtG. Is this special case related to the divergence operation in any way? I will reiterate, I don't know how the divergence operator works in non-Cartesian coordinate schemes. If not, something else I just noted is that according to the paper I read this from, "the radius of the sphere is taken as unity". I don't know what that means, but I'm guessing it's relevant

@KurtG. I was assuming the presence of $\frac{1}{r}$ in (1) where it was absent in (2) might have also been what you were referring to when you mentioned the concept of a special case, so I decided to test (1) to see how the order of magnitude of its computation compared to a per-existing computed divergence. I used a horizontal wind field over the midwest/southeastern United States which was gridded in spherical coordinates (or rather along longitude and latitude), and as I suspected, my computation was 6 orders of magnitude too large. Also, there's the chance I computed it wrong.

@KurtG. I computed it wrong. I didn't convert the velocity vectors $\frac{m}{s}\rightarrow\frac{°}{s}$. My results are now in the desired order of magnitude, however I will add that I performed 2 computations. I used equation (1) for every point, and for the second result, I removed $\sigma$ entirely so the equation would've been $\delta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \lambda}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}$. So after correcting my computation, I've deduced that $\frac{1}{r}$ not being present in (1) should be correct. However something else isn't quite right.

@KurtG. Oh and I used Haversine's formula to convert distance in meters to degrees lon/lat. Anyways, what aside from the declination angle and being in 2-D makes (1) a special case, and does it being special have to do with conditions for when it is used? I ask because using (1) for every single point yielded rather inaccurate results, so I'm guessing there's a use case I'm not aware of.
